# Select each odd/even dt element and its following dds

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a definition that looks like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt>  
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
</dl>
```

Is it possible to construct some selectors that targets only each odd/even dt and it's following dd's without introducing some wrapping markup?

The goal is to give an alternating background color to each dt and it's dd elements.

Here is a link with the markup.

http://jsbin.com/cehudaqobo/edit?html,css,js,output

I tried the suggested solutions but to no avail.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no pure css solution apart having as many selectors as the max number of dd after a dt (`dt:nth-of-type(2n+1),dt:nth-of-type(2n+1)+dd,dt:nth-of-type(2n+1)+dd+dd...`). A very short javascript code would solve the problem, though.

Comment: Ok, thats to complex and non-scalable for my taste. I was looking for a CSS solution as my first choice, but I'll go with the js route on this one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, right now the correct solution is to "fix" the HTML (either with additional element or with a class) or to do some processing client side in js.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with the js solution however. I don't think dl elements can have any other children than dd and dt's (if you care about valid code and semantics.)

Although I guess I could do a new dl for each title..

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not pretty but you will have to specify the '+' rule for the amount of potential dd'

```css
dl dt:nth-of-type(odd),
dl dt:nth-of-type(odd) + dd,
dl dt:nth-of-type(odd) + dd + dd,
dl dt:nth-of-type(odd) + dd + dd + dd
{
  background: blue;
}
dl dt:nth-of-type(even),
dl dt:nth-of-type(even) + dd,
dl dt:nth-of-type(even) + dd + dd,
dl dt:nth-of-type(even) + dd + dd + dd
{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt> 
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Entry</dd>
</dl>
```

I feel that this jQuery would solve your problem more elegantly https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: No, because this only picks the dd closest to each dt.

Comment: And you want any following dd?

Comment: That's what the question says.

Comment: Not *any* following dd, since I want to make a "stop" at each dt. The last dd is also a sibling to the first dt, but I don't want to include that. I only want the dd:s to be influenced by it's preceeding dt element.

If that makes any sense!

Comment: have you thought of using javascript?

Comment: Thanks. It seems js is a better way to do this so I'll go with that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
dd:nth-child(even){ background-color:green;}
</style>
```